# How to configure MoneroD logging

Tags: monerod, logs

Is it possible to configure what monerod is logging to the console?
Specifically I would like to filter out the marked as INC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such ability in Monero. However, `grep`, `sed` and `awk` can be used for this, along with `tail -f`. Remember `--line-buffered` with `grep`.

That should do what you're asking:

```
tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log | grep -v --line-buffered INC
```

The grep pattern might need tightening a bit in case it matches other things with `INC` in the line, though I can't think of one right now.

In the nebulous future, an overhaul of the logging system is planned, which may include an ability to turn on and off different sections of logs.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
monerod --log-file /dev/stdout
```

Comment: thanks, you save my 2hr but I wan ask you one question is "If sync is stoped by any reason should I resume it "?